# ExtJs gridcolumn autosize for different layouts

Tags: extjs, width, autosize, gridpanel

I have a grid and i am trying to autosize its columns after getting data, using autosize() method of sencha. This grid's parent has border layout. autosize() method is not working for in this case.so I tried setting column size using html content.

```
var el = gridObj.el.dom.childNodes[me.el.dom.childElementCount - 1].childNodes[0];
if(el.childNodes.length > 0){
    el =  el.childNodes[el.childElementCount-1];
    if(el.childNodes.length > 0){
var trows =el.childNodes[el.childElementCount - 1].childNodes;
```

this code gave me html 'tr's. looping on them i got some width of column and I set them to respective columns of grid. but i am unable set the sum of those column widths to the grid. this is only case if, parent of grid has border layout or fit layout. For these layouts, i have tried to set grid body width( `gridObj.el.setWidth(400)`),it worked fine, but i am not able to set width to header and top/bottom toolbar in the same way.
can any one help me in resizing columns for these layouts either seeting width to grid or setting width to all(grid header/toolbar/body)?